# find the cluster of a highest number of elements using Kmean?

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using kmean function for clustering 8-D vectors into a set of clusters as:

```
 kmeans(Vectors, clusterCount, labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 2), 10, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

For me the most successful cluster is the one who contains the higher number of vectors. SO my question is how to find the cluster of  highest number of populations? 
label param is an indicator to whom each vector belongs, I feel that if I use it to find the frequency it will consume a time.
is there anybody can suggest an idea?

Traditionally, I did this task as following:

```
int max = -1;int index = -1;
vector<int> classes;
classes.resize(clusterCount);
for (int i=0;i<labels.rows;i++)
{
  int idx = labels.at<int>(i,0);
  classes[idx]++;
  if (classes[idx] > max)
  {
    max = classes[idx];
    index = idx;
 }
}
```

is there a solution faster than this?

Comment: How many samples do you have? Even if you have millions of samples, it will not take much time to find the most frequent one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same, but haven't found anything (yet) that is substantially different, However you can speed up your code:

- don't update your maximum each time
- avoid use of intermediate variables (like your `int idx`)

Here's my code for this:

```
int classes[clusterCount];
memset(classes, 0, sizeof(classes[0]) * clusterCount);
int * labels_ptr = labels.ptr<int>(0);
for (int i = 0; i < labels.rows; ++i)
    classes[*labels_ptr++]++;
for (int i = 0; i < clusterCount; ++i)
    {
    if (classes[i] > max)
        {
        max = count[i];
        index = i;
        }
    }
```

this code gives the same results as yours, and on my pc (intel core i7) goes roughly **5 times** faster than the code you provided (tested on different images for 1000 runs).

Comment: @dervish : if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.